# Golang - Hiding empty struct from JSON Response

Tags: json, google-app-engine, struct, go

I'm trying to make the `Error` and `Success` struct disappear if either one of them is empty

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "net/http"
)

type appReturn struct {
    Suc *Success `json:"success,omitempty"`
    Err *Error   `json:"error,omitempty"`
}

type Error struct {
    Code    int    `json:"code,omitempty"`
    Message string `json:"message,omitempty"`
}

type Success struct {
    Code    int    `json:"code,omitempty"`
    Message string `json:"message,omitempty"`
}

func init() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    j := appReturn{&Success{}, &Error{}}

    js, _ := json.Marshal(&j)
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.Write(js)
}
```

Output:

```
{
    success: { },
    error: { }
}
```

How can I hide the `Error` or `Success` struct from the JSON output?
I thought that sending the pointer as an argument would do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass in `nil` for either argument to make it disappear:

http://play.golang.org/p/9Say6mVzCg

```
j := appReturn{&Success{}, nil}
js, _ := json.Marshal(&j)
fmt.Println(string(js))
j = appReturn{nil, &Error{}}
js, _ = json.Marshal(&j)
fmt.Println(string(js))
j = appReturn{nil, nil}
js, _ = json.Marshal(&j)
fmt.Println(string(js))
```

If for whatever reason you can't do that, you could also write a custom JSON marshaler to check for the empty struct:

http://play.golang.org/p/W0UhB4qtXH

```
func (j appReturn) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    suc, _ := json.Marshal(j.Suc)
    err, _ := json.Marshal(j.Err)
    if (string(err) == "{}") {
       return []byte("{\"success\":" + string(suc) + "}"), nil
    } else {
        return []byte("{\"error\":" + string(err) + "}"), nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because `appReturn.Suc` and `appReturn.Err` are not empty; they contain pointers to *initialized structs*, which just happen to have nil pointers inside. The only empty pointer is a nil pointer.

Initialize appReturn as `j := appReturn{}`